how to update states using state inside setInterval?
I have to update timers every 1 sec. timers is a map. Currently when setInterval is run, it has an closure of the values already present inside it, therefore the time inside it is not updated.

i want to update ids inside timers every second

Please do not post a link to a painting of the code! You can [edit] your question to include the code as formatted text.

Please provide a [mre] as text.

This is a quite common problem. So in React, every time you set the state, you're not modifying the existing state, but creating a new version of it. With your code, you are actually repeatedly using the same state value.
Take a simpler example, let's say you have a state variable count, with an initial value 100, when you call setCount(count + 1) inside the setInterval, you're actually calling setCount(101) every second. The correct way to do it here is setCount(currentCount => currentCount + 1).
So let's go back to your code, you also need to make sure you are updating the state based on your current value. The updated code should look like this:
if (props.isActive) {

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    props.setTimers(currentTimers => {
      const updatedTimers = { ...currentTimers };
      const currentTime = updatedTimers[props.id].time;
      updatedTimers[props.id] = {
        ...updatedTimers[props.id],
        time: currentTime + 1,
      };
      return updatedTimers;
    });
  }, 1000);

}

